# Flex items expanding to content height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox layout to position three divs in a column so that each div has the same height. Each div displays a scrollbar if its content is too large. I would like each section to only expand to the height of its content, but currently what happens is that every section is always the same height regardless of the content in it.

If the container is 900px, each section should be 300px, and if the content of a section is more than 300px tall, a scroll bar should appear. However, if the content of lets say the middle section is only 100px tall, that section should only be 100px, and the remaining sections should fill in the remaining space, so they would each be 400px tall.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x6puccbh/2/

As you can see in this example, the middle section is the same height as the other sections, but I would like it to only be as tall as its content. Is this possible using flex layout?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="header">HEADER</div>
            <div class="content">content<br>content<br>content<br>content
                <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content
                <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <div class="header">HEADER</div>
            <div class="content">content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <div class="header">HEADER</div>
            <div class="content">content<br>content<br>content<br>content
                <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content
                <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

.container {
    height: 300px;
}

.panel {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.section {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your heights to auto I think it does what you are asking. Example and current code below. Let me know if that's not what you were going for

http://plnkr.co/edit/MMjXmANacvZvHofXzYoL

```
    .container {
    height: 300px;
}

.panel {
    max-height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.section {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 33%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: That is what I'm look for, however I need each section to display a scrollbar if the content is too large. In your code, the container is 300px, but the total content height is 500px, yet there are still no scrollbars.

Comment: If you add max-height to the panel, it will still keep the relative sizes while keeping the overall container at 300px. You can add min-height's to the content so that it shows a minimum amount of content as well

Comment: There actually shouldn't be a max height for the panel, I want the panel to stretch to the entire height of its container. Also, the content shouldn't have a minimum height either.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you are looking for. The first example had the panel grow to any size with the size of the sections only being as tall as their content. Without a set height of some sort the content will keep growing. So without setting a height I'm not sure when you want the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: The height of each section should be equaliy divided, so for example, if the container is 900px, each section should be 300px, and if the content of a section is more than 300px tall, a scroll bar should appear. However, if the content of lets say the middle section is only 100px tall, that section should only be 100px, and the remaining sections should fill in the remaining space, so they would each be 400px tall.

Comment: Any ideas? I'm wondering if this is even possible using only CSS.

Comment: I can't think of how to do it. If you set max-width of 33% then it will equally divide it, but then if 1 is smaller it won't give the extra space to the other 2. I'm not sure how to do it with just css

Answer (score -1):

Try setting a max-height property on the container you don't want to get too big but use a vh rather than a % (as in 75vh not 75%).